# Check service of subscription status in app purchase Android

Tags: android, react-native, in-app-purchase

I'm developing an application with react native that will work with in app purchase payments for subscriptions. I tried to find how to manage the subscriptions in both platforms, and I found that Apple notify status changes to your server.

My problem appears with Android, I only found an API to make requests. There is some service from Android like the Apple's service? In case that only API is available, when do you recommend to check the subscription, each 24h, when the user log in?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at this and edit your question afterwards: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation! I tried to edit it as they recommend.